How to prevent my browsers from crashing and how to delete the pcdrm folder and related process that are possibly interfering with my OS?
I had to give an exam on 21.12.24 in https://smart.flexi-workspace.com/. In order to login to VDI I had to install the modules on my local system given below.


After I had done the test I uninstalled the modules.
Unfortunately after that I observed my system behaving strangely as mentioned below.

Both my Opera browser and edge closes randomly on its own. especially my private browsing session.

I am unable to repair or reinstall Opera browser. i also checked but just removing my browsing data or reseting the browser to default.

I checked if the modules I installed were removed properly. I checked the task manager and found this.  

So I tried ending the process but it said. 

So I went to the file location and found that these files. 

So I went on to delete but I am unable to do so even after running cmd as admin and I tried using "takeown" but its not working. I logged in safe mode and tried to delete the files but it keeps telling a

I tried process explorer to kill process but I can't.

I looked into registry to kill "pcdrmsvc" to disable but I can't. It is as if the the admin also doesn't have the right to do "anything" here is one of the properties. 

One of the strange thing is the pcdrm folder where the above files are in, is "read only." It’s stranger when I try to unset ready only, it approves but when I close and reopen properties the folder type changes back to "read only." 




I believe the process is interrupting the other tasks and trying to close it. as if it’s a malware but the digital signtaure is Samsung SDS. Both my Edge and Opera is crashing I don't know if other processes will get disturbed. I have valuable data so its tough and unaffordable to reinstall Windows.
Please help me resolve 2 problems:

How to delete the files and if it’s a malware or virus.

How to prevent my browsers from crashing.



just to give more instight, The processes in the task manager are not consuming a huge load of my cpu/ ram. Its is my belief that these files are probably interfering with my work ing bowser or file deletion as the thing started only after i installed these services. its strange why my broswers are crashing and why i am unable to delete these files. is rest of os the only solution?

These do not seem to be malware, but encryption and other tools that have to be removed more completely. Try a tool such as BCU, https://www.bcuninstaller.com, or alternatives, https://alternativeto.net/software/bulk-crap-uninstaller/, to completely remove those apps. If they were only partially removed, you might have to reinstall 'em before removing completely.

@DrMoishePippik i will try but is it the casue of the repeat crash of both my browsers? what might be casuing the browsers to crash?

You cant delete them because they are running.  Often you can rename them.

Rename them by changing the extension to say txt
Restart your PC
Now you can delete them.

I would suggest that you install a decent anti-virus or malware detection application.

These seem to be encryption tools required by submitter's workplace, not malware. Also, one cannot rename a running application!

i tried but the same issue. it asks for permission and end up getting the "access denied" message even after pressing try again
